# JMeter: each sampler is taking 100 ms

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Im using JMeter for stress testing. Im sending requests in a continuous loop. Actually Latency / Elapsed time shows only 10 ms., but JMeter is not executing the next sampler for another 100 - 120 ms., which is resulting in a delay.
  I really wonder if each sampler takes so much time for preparing to be executed.  Also, generally pre and post processor dont get logged into results csv., so the sample elapsed time included their execution time as well?
  Appreciate the help

## Test Plan

> TestPlan
>
> > Setup Thread Group
> >     Thread Group 1
> >
> > > Random Variable
> > >       User Defined vars
> > >       Loop1
> > >
> > > > Http Request1
> > > >
> > > > > Header Manager
> > > > >           Post Processor (My Own, it really improved performance compared to BeanShell / JSR223)
> > > >
> > > > Http Request2
> > > >
> > > > > Header Manager
> > > >
> > > > Constant Time wait (50ms)
> > >
> > > Loop2
> > >
> > > > Http Request1
> > > >
> > > > > Header Manager
> > > > >           Post Processor (My Own)
> > > >
> > > > Http Request2
> > > >
> > > > > Header Manager
> > > > >           Constant Time wait (10ms)
> >
> > Thread Group 2  #not used at the moment
> >     Thread Group 3  #not used at the moment
> >     Teardown Thread Group

In the Above plan., there is no sleep or anything between HTTP Request 1 & 2., still it is taking 115ms
Thought there is a wait after HTTP Request2 in each loop it is just 10 ms, here it is taking 125 ms.

Thanks,
Rao

Comment: can you share you .jmx file here?

Comment: @BhuwanGautam: Updated the Problem description with the Test Plan steps

Comment: I can see there is a 50ms delay in Loop1 and 10ms delay in Loop2. I had a guess that you have that constant delay there which is causing the problem. Just remove those and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timers are not well understood by JMeter users because they have an odd behavior as stated by the [documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers):

> Note that timers are processed before each sampler in the scope in which they are found; if there are several timers in the same scope, all the timers will be processed before each sampler.

I suggest you to use the [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) to simulate delays as its behavior is easier to understand. Define its duration as the delay you want to simulate and you are set.

Comment: Thanks alot.,that really helps.,